# Was I Fired? Fired, then Boss changed mind? What does that mean?

Tags: employer-relations, employer, employment-agreement

After looking a long-weekend on a software project that needed to be out the client asap, I slept in on Monday morning (my schedule has no set hours).  By the afternoon, I checked my e-mail and found this message from my employer...

> "If we don't see you tomorrow we will interpret your absence as an indication that you have voluntarily terminated employment here and will proceed accordingly."

Several similar messages were found on my phone, saying "You will be fired if you are not in by 11:30."  Needless to say, I certainly was not in the office by the required time, and only made contact with my employer by around 1 or 2 in the afternoon.

**If I failed to be in by the required time "or be fired," does that mean I was fired?**

After giving me a disciplinarian speech about work ethics, my employer didn't make any further mention of my termination.  Does that mean anything?

Many answers I've read here are: "You should get a lawyer."  But for what?  Besides emotional trauma, personal irritation, and stricter rules, I really haven't lost anything of material value.

Does the above count as termination, and if so, does that mean anything for me?

Comment: At least you know now what to do if you’re asked to work on a weekend.

Comment: I'm confused by the contradiction here: *"my schedule has no set hours"* versus *"I certainly was not in the office by the required time"* Do you have a time you are required to be in the office by? Or are there no set hours?

Comment: So many other questions which make it hard to answer. Were you required to work the weekend? Was your boss even aware of your weekend work? Is there an expectation that weekend work is comped as having Monday morning off? Is there mention in your contract or employee handbook of a fixed schedule? Mention in either of a notification process for when you intend to miss the fixed schedule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fired by an Intoxicated Boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83144/fired-by-an-intoxicated-boss). Note I think this is sufficiently similar, because the boss's words differ from their actions.

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause: It is also different, in that intoxicated verbal agreements can affect the legality of an agreement, compared to non-intoxicated, written statements.

Comment: @dwizum: I am not required to be in the office at any time by my hours.  This was suddenly a new requirement, that came with the e-mail.

Comment: Are you sure there's no requirement (in a contract or employee handbook), or have you just been working as if there was none?

Comment: @dwizum: Since I've started (4 years ago), I set my own weekly schedule every Monday whenever I come in.  The employee handbook only mentions following this schedule.

Answer (score 11):

In your conversation with your employer, did you point out that you'd worked over the weekend to make his company more successful?

If so, and he was still ranting, I wouldn't bother with a lawyer, I'd just start looking for a new position, as your efforts aren't appreciated.

Comment: It was indeed mentioned.  This is the avenue I am looking toward now.

Answer (score 3):

> Many answers I've read here are: "You should get a lawyer." But for what?

You should get a lawyer so that you can better interpret your contract in the context of your local laws. This is clearly some serious miscommunication between you and your boss.

You should've notified your boss in a timely manner that you can't make it in today in time, due to exhaustion or any other reason

Your boss shouldn't have rushed to pressure you, since Things Happen and people sometimes can't make it in time. That's a Douchebag Move<sup>TM</sup> in my book but I'm not the one dealing with him, you are. What if you were in an accident and the first thing you saw when you woke up was that not only is half your body in a cast, but you're also effectively fired.

You must both get your expectations sorted. This includes perks after pulling off feats like working the entire weekend.